# Getting Could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. with MSALv2.js

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSALv2.js and my app always loads, but recently I have started to get this error sometimes when calling the aquiretoken method. It doesn't consistently occur, just sometimes. Does anyone know why this is and how to resolve that?

```
{
    "errorCode": "endpoints_resolution_error",
    "errorMessage": "Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientConfigurationError: untrusted_authority: The provided authority is not a trusted authority. Please include this authority in the knownAuthorities config parameter.",
    "subError": "",
    "name": "ClientAuthError"
}
```

Comment: Hi, @omega, did you find the root cause? I am facing the same problem, it occur occasionally